# Angularjs - In navigation ng-repeat display more rows during randering

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have pagination on my page (**5** rows in a single page)
when change the page number first it turns into **10** rows for a moment then next **5** of them display.

I want to improve user experience that when he change the page number he will not get any feeling of UI disturbance.

here is my pagination code.

```
$scope.currentPage = cPage
    , $scope.numPerPage = PerPage
    , $scope.maxSize = maxNavSize;

$scope.numPages = function () {
    return Math.ceil(dataLength / $scope.numPerPage);
};
if (watchFun)
    watchFun()

watchFun = $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.cPage = $scope.currentPage;
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage),
        end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

    // ajax call to get data for each page
    $http({
        url: url+ '?'+data + "&offset=" + begin + "&limit=" + PerPage,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }) .success(function (response) {
            if (response.length != 0) {
                      $scope.historyContest =[];
                      $scope.historyContest = response;
           }

        });
});
```

**$scope.historyContest** represent ng-repeat so it will change for each page.

If you people have any confusion in question please let me know I will update it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can this solve your problem?

```
 if (response.length != 0) {
  $scope.historyContest =[];
  $timeout(function(){
      $scope.historyContest = response;
  },100); 
}
```